# Example of nonempty scheme with no closed points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I know that when a scheme $X$ is quasicompact, every point has a closed point in it's closure. This of course means that every nonempty quasicompact scheme has a closed point. If we drop the assumption that $X$ is quasicompact,  it may no longer be true that $X$ contains a closed point. Is there a fairly easy example of this phenomenon?

I also want to better understand how to come up with these sorts of examples in the future, so if possible, could you briefly describe the general process you took to construct the example.

Comment: If we know that $X$ is quasicompact, we can cover it by finitely many affine schemes $U_i = Spec(R_i)$ for some ring $R_i$, i=1,..,n. Since $U_1$ is affine, we can choose a closed point $x_1$ corresponding to a maximal ideal in $A_1$. $x_1$ may not be closed in $X$. If it is, we are done, otherwise we can choose $x_2\neq x_1$ in the closure of $x_1$. $x_2$ is not contained in $U_1$ so without loss of generality, assume it's in $U_2$. If $x_2$ is closed in $X$, we are done, otherwise continue the process. Finitely many $U_i$ means this process terminates with a closed point in $X$.

Comment: My comment was in response to a previous comment which has since been deleted. I was asked how to prove that nonempty quasicompact schemes always have a closed point, so with the limited space I highlighted the proof above.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering how you were thinking of this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that Karl Schwede has a very nice example and explanation of how to construct a nonempty scheme with no closed points. Here is the link:

http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/schwede03.pdf